# Eureka cluster :org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: netflix-eureka

I'm getting an Exception when trying to build a Spring Cloud Eureka cluster

> :org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException

Here is the three application.yml of eureka server

server_7001

[image: server_7001]

server_7002

[image: server_7002]

server_7003

[image: server_7003]

and the application.yml of the service provider

Service provider

[image: service provider]

I can start server_7001, server_7002 and server_7003 successfully. But while running the service provider, getting an exception as shown below

[image: --!]

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/hosts` of `server_7001`, 
`server_7002` and `server_7003`

Define :

```
ip_address_of_server_7001 eureka7001.com 
ip_address_of_server_7002 eureka7002.com 
ip_address_of_server_7003 eureka7003.com
```